# SonarQube: Bytecode of dependencies missing despite Maven usage

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-maven-plugin

I use the sonar-maven-plugin version 3.4.0.905 to SonarQube-scan a flat hierarchy, multi-module Maven project.
I have noticed a warning in the log of one of the 14 modules I scan.

> [WARNING] Bytecode of dependencies was not provided for analysis of
>   source files, you might end up with less precise results. Bytecode can
>   be provided using sonar.java.libraries property

What could cause this issue?
My understanding is that the sonar.java.libraries property only needs to be used when not using Maven. Am I mistaken? How can I best troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Can you prepare an example project or add content of your `pom.xml` files?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line of code in your sonar-project.properties file:

`sonar.java.binaries=**/target/classes`

You can read more info at: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/java/

Answer (score 0):

You've to add **sonar.java.libraries** as well. In this attribute you can add comma-separated paths to files with third-party libraries (JAR or Zip files) that are used by your project. Wildcards can be used:

Examples:

`sonar.java.libraries=path/to/Library.jar,directory/**/*.jar`